# how to Check if String is of particular format in C#

Tags: c#, string, format, compare

I want to check if the string values are of form

```
i) 6.2.****.0

ii) 6.2.****.0000
```

Where * represents any digit from 1-9

How can I achieve this using C#? Pl let me know which way (with less code) can help me achive this? If I can use Regular Expressions, how to use the same to achieve the above checks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're just looking for the number portion (not the `i)` prefix) and there must be 4 digits then try the following

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"6\.2\.[1-9]{4}\.0+")) {
  // It's a match
}
```

Note: This will actually match that particular pattern anywhere in the string.  If you want to see if the entire string matches that pattern then you need to use the following

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(theString, @"^6\.2\.[1-9]{4}\.0+$")) {
  // It's a match
}
```

Comment: I think 'd' would also consider digit '0' which I do not need.
I guess then I use [1-9] in place of \d in the Regular Expression?

Comment: @stack_pointerisEXTINCT my bad, forgot 0 was invalid.  Switched it to `[1-9]`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"(^6\.2\.[1-9]{4}\.0{4}$)") || Regex.IsMatch(text, @"(^6\.2\.[1-9]{4}\.0$)"))
{
    // some code
}
```

or

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(text, @"(\A6\.2\.[1-9]{4}\.0{4}\Z|\A6\.2\.[1-9]{4}\.0\Z)"))
{
    // some code
}
```

Comment: you can replace '^' with '\A' and '$' with '\Z' as well.